# Pandas: how to check if there is a series of positive values after another column specific value

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
time                    price               macd    signal          macd_histogram  cross
25  2019-01-01 11:38:45 0.00224311  2.502858e-06    2.502858e-06    0.000000e+00    D
26  2019-01-01 11:39:15 0.00224473  2.664147e-06    2.535116e-06    1.290311e-07    D
27  2019-01-01 11:39:30 0.00224422  2.722738e-06    2.572640e-06    1.500983e-07    R
28  2019-01-01 11:40:15 0.00224899  3.095925e-06    2.677297e-06    4.186282e-07    D
29  2019-01-01 11:40:15 0.00224697  3.203015e-06    2.782441e-06    4.205739e-07    D
30  2019-01-01 11:42:00 0.00224668  3.229429e-06    2.871838e-06    3.575910e-07    D
31  2019-01-01 11:45:00 0.00224967  3.438117e-06    2.985094e-06    4.530229e-07    D
32  2019-01-01 11:48:30 0.00224967  3.563519e-06    3.100779e-06    4.627398e-07    R
33  2019-01-01 11:52:30 0.00224983  3.634026e-06    3.207429e-06    4.265979e-07    D
34  2019-01-01 11:52:45 0.00225143  3.768580e-06    3.319659e-06    4.489214e-07    D
```

What I need is for every value in the column `cross` which are equal to R, check if the next 5 values (starting at the same index) in the column `macd_histogram` are positive or negative. I have no clue on how to proceed, especially checking the next 5... any help is more than welcome! Thanks

Comment: You mean, whether the 5 values in the `macd_histogram` for rows `i` to `i+4` all have the same sign (where `i` is any of the rows where `cross == 'R'`)?

Comment: Yes exactly! Sorry I did not explain well

Comment: I just wanted to confirm it with a different phrasing. 'Cause the exact wording "check if the next 5 values [...] are positive or negative" could be interpreted as "being any number but zero, whether positive or negative".

Comment: Hmm yes there was something wrong, i wasnt checking for exaclty the 5 next, but rather 5 after an 'R'. Tricky one this

Comment: It is the 5 after an 'R'. If those 5 values after an R in the `macd_histogram` are positive then I would like to create another column whith the value True. If those 5 values in the `macd_histogram` are negative then False. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: what if one is positive and another value is negative????

Comment: What about zero? I think the mathematical take is that zero is neither positive nor negative, but practically, you may prefer positive, negative, or even either of them.

Comment: I'd just create a loop, looping over the row indices where `cross == 'R'`. Then it's relatively easy to index `macd_histogram[i:i+5]` and see if they're all positive or all negative.

Comment: How about the situation where there are only 3 or less rows between consecutive `R`s in the cross column?

Comment: @Viktor.w check it, now it should work fine

Comment: `g = df.cross.eq('R').cumsum()`,
`df.macd_histogram.gt(0).groupby(g).transform(lambda x: x.iloc[:5].sum()).ge(5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['D', 'D', 'R', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'R', 'D', 'D', 'D'], 'col2': [0, -1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, -3, 1, 2]})

index = df[df['col'] == 'R'].index.values
df['output'] = False
print(index)

for i in index:
    macd_histogram_list = df.loc[i:i+4, 'col2'].tolist()
    print(macd_histogram_list)
    if all(j >= 0 for j in macd_histogram_list):
        df.loc[i:i+4, 'output'] = True # positive
        continue
    if all(j < 0 for j in macd_histogram_list):
        df.loc[i:i+4, 'output'] = True # negative

print(df)
```

**output:**

```
   col  col2  output
0    D     0   False
1    D    -1   False
2    R     0    True
3    D     1    True
4    D     2    True
5    D     0    True
6    D     1    True
7    R     2   False
8    D    -3   False
9    D     1   False
10   D     2   False
```

Comment: I don't know about the case if there are less then 4  `D`'s